# manage permissions per list

Tags: permissions, security, groups, inheritance

I have a SharePoint 2007 Foundation portal with about 20 sites, each mirrored per client differing only in membership groups and client-specific content.  The person who set up the site created 2 Lists, one named "Portfolio" and one is "Uploads," and they are otherwise identical.   The purpose is to distinguish the company-side and client-side uploads during the engagement.

I am trying to fix the following problem: Often client will mistakenly upload in "Portfolio."  I attempted to remove access for this list by selecting the list, clicking

> Portfolio -> Settings -> Permissions and Management | Permissions for this document Libary

I see the following message: *This library inherits permissions from its parent Web site. To manage permissions directly, click Edit Permissions from the Actions menu.*

If I edit permissions from the parent website, removing add privileges this would effect the *Upload* list as well.

Is there a way I can remove "Add" permissions to one list but not the other, or remove inheritance permissions for the Site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft didn't win any awards for that alert message.  You need to edit the permissions on the Portfolio list itself.  When you do that, it breaks inheritance and copies the site permissions to the list.  From there, you can trim the list permissions down as needed without affecting the site permissions.

Bear in mind that if your clients have 'Full Control' permissions on the site then they can simply override this ... though, most won't know how.

Comment: I am a site collection Administrator so I should have the proper permissions.  I can't navigate to where you are describing, can you provide more details?  Under the ACTIONS menu for the portfolio, as a site collections administrator I see the following:   Export To Spreadsheet, View RSS Feed, Alert Me.

Comment: The list permissions are managed in the place you mention in your original note.  Browse to the list, select Settings- List Settings, then click on 'permissions for this list.' On the List Permissions page, you merely need to 'Actions - Edit Permissions' for it to create a unique Access Control List for only that list.